# PostgreSQL - Fetch only a specified limit of related rows but with a number indicating the total count

Tags: postgresql

Basically I have 2 models like so:

Comments:

```
+----+--------+----------+-----------------+
| id | userId | parentId | text            |
+----+--------+----------+-----------------+
| 2  | 5      | 1        | Beautiful photo |
+----+--------+----------+-----------------+
| 3  | 2      | 2        | Thanks Jeff.    |
+----+--------+----------+-----------------+
| 4  | 7      | 2        | Thank you, Jeff.|
+----+--------+----------+-----------------+
```

This table is designed to handle **threads**. Each `parentId` is a comment itself.

And CommentLikes:

```
+----+--------+-----------+
| id | userId | commentId |
+----+--------+-----------+
| 1  | 2      | 2         |
+----+--------+-----------+
| 2  | 7      | 2         |
+----+--------+-----------+
| 3  | 7      | 3         |
+----+--------+-----------+
```

What I'm trying to achieve is an SQL query that will perform the following (given the parameter `parentId`):
Get a limit of 10 replies that belong to `parentId`. With each reply, I need a count indicating the **total** number of replies to that reply and another count indicating the **total** number of likes given to that reply.

Sample input #1: `/replies/1`

Expected output:

```
[{
id: 2,
userId: 5,
parentId: 1,
text: 'Beautiful photo',
likeCount: 2,
replyCount: 2
}]
```

Sample input #2: `/replies/2`

Expected output:

```
[
{
id: 2,
userId: 2,
parentId: 2,
text: 'Thanks Jeff.'
replyCount: 0,
likeCount: 1
},
{
id: 3,
userId: 7,
parentId: 2,
text: 'Thank you, Jeff.'
replyCount: 0,
likeCount: 0
}
]
```

I'm trying to use Sequelize for my case but it seems to only over-complicate things so any raw SQL query will do.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Add sample datas and expected result

Comment: @Philippe Added a sample to my current small example. I'll extend it a little more to make it more clear.

Comment: @Philippe 2 cases added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about something like this

```
SELECT *,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comment_likes WHERE comments.id =comment_likes."commentId")  AS likecount,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments AS c WHERE c."parentId" = comments.id) AS commentcount
FROM  comments
WHERE comments."parentId"=2
```